# Web scraping with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I like to scrap out of the cisco page the EoL link.
In firefox / inspector I see all the needed information.
But using requests or urllib, I can't get the needed information.
Only a part of the website is in the responds.

search result should be:

p class="url">
www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches…
"""

or

3560V2 ...

### My code:

```
import requests
url = "http://tools.cisco.com/search/results/en/us/get#q=End-
       of-Sale+and+End-of-Life+Announcement+%2B+3560V2+"
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
raw = ""
for item in r:
  raw = raw + str(r.content)

>>> raw.find("3560V2")
-1
>>> raw.find('p class="url"')
-1
>>> raw.find('www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switc')
-1
```

==> no success.

But inspector of firefox is showing this information.

Any help is welcome.

regards,
Thomas

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct links?

Answer (score 0):

What is it for?

```
for item in r:
   raw = raw + str(r.content)
```

why do you need to iterate over the response content? Isn't it enought: `print(r.text)`?

```
raw.find(...)
```

What is the `find` method of the `raw` string?

Answer (score 0):

Sure r.text should be enough.
I found that using iteration brings more content. But if that makes sense, good questions.
Here is one of my first tries:
(the 3560V2 link is not found, but I can see it using firefox inspector)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://tools.cisco.com/search/results/en/us/get#q=End-  
       of-Sale+and+End-of-Life+Announcement+%2B+3560V2+'

r = requests.get(url, verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
    print (link.get("href"))  # print links
```